# BrowserSync on Docker is running correctly and able to detect changes, but browser doesn't seems to be triggered/reloaded

Tags: node.js, docker, browser-sync

Source code can be found from: https://github.com/kevinchu-work/Docker_with_BrowserSync (Resolved & Completely working fine now)

I am trying a very simple Node Docker + BrowserSync + Gulp working together, but the browser never able to reload

Node: app.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1><div>'+Math.random().toString(36)+'</div>');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

gulpfile.js: nodemon & browser-sync

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {

  var started = false;

  return nodemon({
    script: 'app.js',
    env: {
      port: 3000
    },
    ignore: [
      'gulpfile.js',
      'node_modules/'
    ]
  }).on('start', function () {
    if (!started) {
      started = true;
      cb();
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', gulp.series(['nodemon'], function () {
// gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
  browserSync.init('*.js', {
    open: false,
    proxy: "localhost:3000",
    // files: ["**/*.js"],
    // port: 3000,
    // notify: false
  });
// });
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync', function () {
  gulp.watch(["*.*"], function() { console.log("sync"); browserSync.reload; });
}));
```

startDocker: setup the docker

```
docker pull node
docker run -t -i -v $(pwd):/app -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -p:3002:3002 dev /bin/bash
```

Already, once the docker started & running, the following command trigger the node

```
cd /app
yarn install
yarn global add gulp
gulp
```

The node, nodemon running very well but the PORT shifted from 3000 to 3001 (ok, i can live with it), but it never trigger the refresh on browser side. I did open localhost:3001 and it running very well.

This is the output when running the previous command

```
root@5f80167a4a37:/project# gulp
[16:20:01] Using gulpfile /project/gulpfile.js
[16:20:01] Starting 'default'...
[16:20:01] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[16:20:01] Starting 'nodemon'...
[16:20:01] Finished 'nodemon' after 405 ms
[16:20:01] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[16:20:01] [nodemon] 2.0.4
[16:20:01] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[16:20:01] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[16:20:01] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[16:20:01] [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:3000
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3001
    External: http://172.17.0.2:3001
 -----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://localhost:3002
 -----------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
[16:21:14] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[16:21:14] [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

The Browsersync did detect changes of files and execute reloading but browser. Any idea?

Comment: I finally solved the issue myself, the reason of BrowserSync can't trigger/info browser to reload because of the HTML body is NOT a valid HTML structure, which became a blocker to BrowserSync to inject necessary JS.

And the solution is 

```res.end('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');```

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable (and encouraged) to self-answer here and (after a fixed length of time), to accept your own answer.

Comment: :-) I am happy that I found the reason after nearly 5 days of try and error